# How to move between Nautilus panes?

Tags: nautilus, firefox, shortcut-keys, shortcuts, tabs

I believe Nautilus is the file system in Ubuntu.
When I have two tabs open, in say my home directory, how do I move between them easily?

Is there a shortcut key?

For example:
In Firefox, Ctrl + Tab allows you move directly between tabs and that would be very useful in my own file system.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Num</kbd> will move you to the tab that <kbd>Num</kbd> corresponds to. So:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> for the first tab.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> for the second tab.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> for the third tab.

and so on.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, very helpful wonder why it wasn't included in other short cut manuals

Answer (score 6):

- <kbd>Alt + Num</kbd> for direct access; and
- <kbd>Ctrl+PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+PgDn</kbd> to navigate sequentially through tabs.

Comment: It looks like <kbd>Ctrl+PageUp</kbd> doesn't work in GNOME 40

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid duplicating comments, see this answer for a working Ctrl+Tab:

[How can I change the keybindings in Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035845/how-can-i-change-the-keybindings-in-nautilus/#1209754)