# How to switch between tabs with keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, tabs

**How can I switch between tabs with keyboard in `ubuntu`?**

In windows I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: What tabs? a browser? nautilus?

Comment: in case nautilus: http://askubuntu.com/questions/147017/how-to-move-between-nautilus-panes

Comment: In some cases Ctrl+PgUp/Dn works, but not in many others, i.e. in keyboard settings switch between `typing` and `shortcuts` tabs or in appearance settings between `look` and `behavior` tabs.

Comment: I can use ctrl+tab in ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycle tabs (also: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> = open new tab, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> = close tab) is now being implemented in many applications that use tabs:

- internet browsers like Chrome, Firefox, Opera,
- file managers (Nautilus, Nemo, Dolphin, PCManFM),
- also Audacious, Clementine, Adobe Reader, Pidgin, Qbittorrent, WPS Office suite.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found it.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up/Down</kbd> and if didn't work add and <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up/Down</kbd> (and still doesn't work in some apps :( ).

I think if it was like `Windows` it was very easier. I used to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> in all apps like Chrome, Firefox, Settings in Control Panel and tabs in every app that had tabs in it.