# How can I change the keybindings in Nautilus?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, nautilus, shortcut-keys

I'd like to change the keybindings in Nautilus. Specifically, I'd like to make it so <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> cycles between tabs instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>PgUp</kbd> / <kbd>PgDn</kbd>. I can't seem to find anything in `dconf`, and Nautilus only lists the shortcuts and doesn't let me change them. I tried using the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287936/changing-nautilus-key/288403#288403), but (1) the file `~/.config/nautilus/accels` does not exist, so I can't figure out the syntax/lines I'm supposed to edit, and (2) making the file and copying their code into it didn't do anything. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Whatever is shown in dconf-editor > org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings can be edited. An accels map is no longer used so it would be useless..

Comment: I looked in org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings, and it only seems to contain keyboard shortcuts for moving windows, not for Nautilus, specifically. Is there anywhere else in dconf that I might find keybindings for Nautilus?

Comment: Take a look here, seems to the only way for custom accels, https://askubuntu.com/questions/680016/keyboard-shortcut-for-open-terminal-nautilus-3-16/696901#696901

Answer (score 4):

You can, but it's not easy:  The standard parameters of Nautilus do not allow you to change these keybindings as there are no configuration parameters for them:

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep --ignore-case nautilus
```

So you have 2 possibilities:

1. Switch to Nemo, which has the capabilities you seek out of the box (and more ...)
2. Clone the source of Nautilus, edit the source code, change <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and build your own version:

   ```
   cd Documents
   git clone https://github.com/GNOME/nautilus
   cd nautilus/src
   grep --recursive --ignore-case tabs *
   nano nautilus-window.c #This is where you need to do more work yourself
   cd ..
   ./configure
   make
   sudo checkinstall
   ```

That's as far as I want to go, because I took the easy way and deployed Nemo because I abhor the direction the GNOME developers took as they prefer "simplicity", whereas I like my stuff complex and full of features.

#### Sorry! ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Thanks @Fabby. :) What does the `grep --recursive --ignore-case tabs *` line do? just because of the word `tabs`, it makes me think that it might be related to the original particulars. personally, i don't care about that particular shortcut, and accordingly wanna see if that's needed for any other use case, or if should be a different command for different keybindings. 

And thanks for the Nemo suggestion - sounds like the better way to go. :)

Comment: It shows you all the source code files containing the word tabs.  **0:-)** *I think it's nautilus-window.c you need,* **but YMMV.**  Go Nemo, like I did: nemo has a lot of bells and whistles and is far superior to Nautilus, though very similar in its basic usage. @thisissami  You'll feel right at home.

Answer (score 4):

This shows up high when googling, but doesn't mention one of the solutions working in 2020, so here you go...

The accels are modifiable through the python-nautilus (nautilus-python in non-Debian-based distros) interface. We install the package and create a plugin:

```
sudo apt install python-nautilus
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/nautilus-python/extensions
nano ~/.local/share/nautilus-python/extensions/CtrlTab.py
```

Then insert the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import gi
gi.require_version('Nautilus', '3.0')
from gi.repository import GObject, Nautilus, Gtk

class CtrlTab(GObject.GObject, Nautilus.LocationWidgetProvider):
    def get_widget(self, uri, window):
        app = Gtk.Application.get_default()
        app.set_accels_for_action("win.tab-previous", ["<shift><control>Tab", "<control>Page_Up"])
        app.set_accels_for_action("win.tab-next", ["<control>Tab", "<control>Page_Down"])
```

Save, exit and make sure nautilus gets shut down with:

```
nautilus -q
```

Comment: Working perfectly on Ubuntu 18.04.5.

Comment: Worked for me on Pop OS 21.04, but the package was called `python3-nautilus`.

Answer (score 2):

### Old Bug

This is an old bug appearing in many bug reports. This [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/hundredpapercuts/+bug/388508) is from 2009.

FireFox and Windows both support <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> for switching tabs. On many laptops <kbd>Page Up</kbd> might be hard to reach or poorly labeled. Even on most desktop keyboards  <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd> is impossible to perform with the left hand.

For one-handed shortcuts you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> for the first tab, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> for the second tab, etc.

[Gnome's design](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/keyboard-nav.html.en) is for <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is used for switching panes within windows. For example from the main pane to the left side pane.

---

### Suggested `gsettings` hack that doesn't seem to work

A "hack" in this [bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=738325) illustrates these two `gsettings` you can view before changing:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/keybindings/ next-tab
'<Control>Page_Down'
$ gsettings get org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/keybindings/ prev-tab
'<Control>Page_Up'
```

Then to change them use:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/keybindings/next-tab '<Primary>Tab'
$ gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/keybindings/prev-tab '<Primary><Shift>Tab'
```

This successfully changes behavior switching between `gnome-terminal` tabs but has no effect in Nautilus or even YAD.